# Activate session_start with a $_POST submit

Tags: php, html, post, session-variables

I  have a .php 1 where I want it to shows/echoes $_SESSION VARIABLES coming from another .php 2. The thing is, I just realized (I think) that session_start send variables automarically when webpage starts, but, I don't want that, I just want to start session when the user click on the button. Please, I have researching this so hard.

PHP 1:

```
session_start();
//session.auto_start();
unset($_SESSION['manufacturer']);

if (!isset($_SESSION['manufacturer'] )) {

    echo 'VALUES!!!';

    $manufacturerTo = ($_SESSION['manufacturer']); 

} else {

    echo 'NO VALUES!!!';
//    unset($_SESSION['manufacturer']);
    $manufacturerTo = ($_SESSION['manufacturer']); 
//    session_destroy();
}

echo'<tr>';
echo"<td><label for='updateManufacturer'>Manufacturer:</label></td> <td><input type='text' name='updateManufacturer' value='$manufacturerTo'></input></td>";   
echo'</tr>';
```

PHP 2:

```
} else if (isset($_POST['updateShowAircraft'])) {

// session_start();

//    echo 'BUTTON WAS READ';



        if (!empty($_POST['updateBN'])) {

//            echo 'A VALUE';

//            session_start();

            $buno = $_POST['updateBN'];

            $databaseDAO = new DatabaseDAO();
//       
        $aircraftDTO = $databaseDAO->showUpdateAircraft($buno);
//        

//        
//                
                $manufacturer = $aircraftDTO->getManufacturer();
//                $role = $aircraftDTO->getRole();
//                $name = $aircraftDTO->getName();
//                $cvw = $aircraftDTO->getCVW();
//                $cvn = $aircraftDTO->getCVN();
//                $squadron = $aircraftDTO->getSquadron();
//                
                  session_start();
//                
//                session.auto_start == On;
//                
                $_SESSION['manufacturer'] = $manufacturer;
//                $_SESSION['role'] = $role; 
//                $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
//                $_SESSION['cvw'] = $cvw;
//                $_SESSION['cvn'] = $cvn;
//                $_SESSION['squadron'] = $squadron;

                 header('Location: ../webpages/DatabasePage.php');



        }else{

//            echo 'ISNT A VALUE';
            header('Location: ../webpages/DatabasePage.php');
        }
```

Comment: PHP is a server side language and sessions are server side variables.  Nothing is sent unless you want it to be.  I think you better clarify why you need to start sessions conditionally because it sounds to me like you are overthinking this.

Comment: Let me explain. In PHP 1 I have a form with a input and a submit. On the bottom of this PHP, there is a block that reads the incoming $_SESSION variable from PHP 2 executing and echo message depending if the $_SESSION exists or not. On the other hand in PHP 2, I have a function when is wondering if the input and submit has been setted, if so, it will creates $_SESSION variables, being sending to the PHP 1 to be processed and the result be displayed. I just realized that session sends variables automatically when I run the webpage, and I don't want that. Please help me!!! I'm in a trouble here.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['your_button'])){session_start();} - note that you must call session_start() before doing any output

Comment: Didn't work dude!!! After submit, the session is not loaded. I tested just in case w/ session_status. I don't know why. Regards.